# zeros at start were not fetching while reading the table data in specflow

Tags: specflow

I want to read table data from the specflow feature file.

Table value is **'000085'**

When I create a sales quotation from the table:

> | CustomerAccount |
>
> | 000085          |

```
//Code:

 public void CreateSalesQuotation(Table table)
        {
           dynamic tableData = table.CreateDynamicInstance();
           int x = tableData.CustomerAccount;

        }
```

Result: 
    Expected value is 000085 but actual value i am getting in x variable is 85

Answer (score 1):

**What is the version of specflow?**

Better you use **CreateInstance** rather than **CreateDynamicInstance** to avoid extra operation on string.

```
public void CreateSalesQuotation(Table table)
        {
            var tableData = table.CreateInstance<Customer>();
            var value = tableData.CustomerAccount;
        }

 internal class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerAccount { get; set; }
    }
```

**Result:** Expected value is 000085 and actual value is 000085

Comment: @GangadharGVL: This should be your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions: Using this as a string from the start. Since probably in the database this is a char or varchar as well (similar to string).

```
string x = tableData.CustomerAccount;
//value is 000085
```

Or you could manipulate the integer to a string with leading zeros.

```
 int x = tableData.CustomerAccount;
 //now it is 85
 string y = x.ToString();
 //we convert to string so we can use padleft
 string z = y.PadLeft(2, '0');
 //this will add 2 zeros to the beginning of the string.
```

Ofcourse you would want to optimize this last bit so that the leading zeros are correct.